# Manifest Too Large Error when Running a Redshift Query

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have programamtically created some external tables in Redshift based on csv files.  For reference the table creation code looks like this:

```
        StringBuilder createSQL = new StringBuilder(
            $@"CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE temp.{tablename} (");
        for (int i = 0; i < colCount; i++)
        {
            if (i == colCount - 1)
            {
                createSQL.Append($"{cols.ElementAt(i)} VARCHAR(500))");
            }
            else
            {
                createSQL.Append($"{cols.ElementAt(i)} VARCHAR(500),");
            }
        }
        createSQL.Append($"LOCATION 's3://{storageBucket}/{keystring}'");
        Console.WriteLine($"Executing query to create table {tablename}...");
        ExecuteStatement(createSQL.ToString());
```

The table creation works fine, or seems to.  The issue I'm running into now it moving data from these external tables to standard tables in Redshift.  In fact I can't even query these external tables.  Here is an example:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT id, 'some_string' 
  FROM temp.external1
```

This simple query returns with the error:

```
ERROR: Manifest too large Detail: ----------------------------------------------- error: Manifest too large code: 9002 context: Manifest with key=A/B/C/file.csv too large 967567324 > 104857600 query: 16876 location: scan_range_manager.cpp:386 process: padbmaster [pid=11260] ----------------------------------------------- [ErrorId: 1-621514cb-5963a7056eaa979b025adcd2]
```

Unfortunately I haven't been able to find much documentation on the error I'm getting and was wanting to know if anyone has any insight on this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Found my problem.  During the table creation I was passing in an S3 URI was that fully qualified to the file itself.

```
key=A/B/C/file.csv
```

This cause the creation to take that as a manifest file.  In order to pass in the file as a reference to populate the table I need to only pass in the FOLDER that holds the .csv, no the path with the csv it self.

```
key=A/B/C/
```

Correcting this fixed my problem.